# Maven “shaded” plugin does not create shadedClassifierName file in the traget directory

Tags: maven, plugins, jquery-plugins, maven-shade-plugin

I just added `<pluginManagement>` tag to my pom after that when i build, maven does not create shadedClassifierName jar file "**paria-java-1.0.73-SNAPSHOTjar-with-dependencies.jar**" in the target directory.

**Any idea what is wrong?**

```
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
     <!-- original version 2.1 -->
     <version>3.2.0</version> 
     <configuration>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
        <filters>
           <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                 <exclude>jdbc.properties_vb</exclude>
                 <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                 <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                 <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                 <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE*</exclude>
                 <exclude>META-INF/license.txt</exclude>
                 <exclude>META-INF/NOTICE*</exclude>
                 <exclude>META-INF/notice.txt</exclude>
                 <exclude>LICENSE</exclude>
                 <exclude>license.txt</exclude>
                 <exclude>NOTICE</exclude>
                 <exclude>overview.html</exclude>
                 <exclude>readme.txt</exclude>
                 <exclude>testpool.jocl</exclude>
                 <exclude>XPP3_1.1.4c_MIN_VERSION</exclude>
              </excludes>
           </filter>
        </filters>
        <transformers>
           <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.
  resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <manifestEntries>
                 <Main-Class>be.baba.tar.upload.Run</Main-Class>
              </manifestEntries>
           </transformer>
        </transformers>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
        <execution>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
     </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: You need to add it outside the pluginManagement...

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, thanks to @khmarbaise 
It need to be added outside the pluginManagement.